# Simplify moving a branch on top of another with fewer commands and without temporary branch

Tags: git

I have this situation:

```
A - B - C - D - E [branch2]
     \
      F - G - H [branch1]
```

and I want to achieve this:

```
A - B - C - D - E - F' - G' - H' [branch2]
     \
      F - G - H [branch1]
```

I can do it with these commands::

```
git branch -D tmp
git checkout -b tmp branch1
git rebase branch2
git checkout -B branch2
```

Is there a single command to replace this sequence? I think some sort of `rebase --onto` might do it but I am confused by that :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just

```
git rebase branch2 branch1^0 && git checkout -B branch2
```

or

```
git checkout -B branch2 branch1; git rebase branch2@{1}
```

See [`git help revisions`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtltngtemegemHEADv1510em) for the naming syntax, `^0` is an extension of "parent number n", with 0 taken to mean "this commit itself not the name I'm using to refer to it", when rebase sees the expression as an arg it knows not to re-hang the label on the rebased commits, it'll leave you with a no-label new tip which you then re-hang the `branch2` label on.

The other sequence re-hangs the `branch2` label first  and then uses "where this label was before I moved it" syntax as the rebase target.

Comment: Y'all are waayyyy overcomplicating this by trying to force-fit it. It's very simple: rebase branch1 onto branch2 but leave the label behind, thne hang the branch2 label  on the new tip. That's what OP's command sequence achieves, that's what this shorter sequence achieves by replacing the temporary branch names with equivalent and and already-Git-suppliled revision expressions -- Git supplying so many of those expression formats because it's easier to just say what you want directly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the OP wants to copy branch1 into branch2 and leave branch1 alone. They have this.

```
A - B - C - D - E [branch2]
     \
      1 - 2 - 3 [branch1]
```

They want this.

```
A - B - C - D - E - 1A - 2A - 3A [branch2]
     \
      1 - 2 - 3 [branch1]
```

This is done with [git cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).

```
git switch branch2
git cherry-pick branch2..branch1
```

`branch2..branch1` means the commits reachable from branch1 (A - B - 1 - 2 - 3) excluding those reachable from branch2 (A - B - C - D - E). The result copies only commits (1 - 2 -3). See [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_dotted_range_notations) and [git cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).

If you want to keep empty commits, use `--allow-empty`. However, you generally want to skip empty commits as they indicate the branch already has that change.

(While you could cram this into a single command, I don't recommend it if you're not very familiar with Git. It's not wise to treat Git as a bunch of commands.)

Comment: `git cherry-pick`  will be enough in OP's exact drawn history but rebase is needed if there are any complications at all, it's written to handle (almost) all the related cases as simply, or close to it, as a direct cherry-pick handles the simplest one.

Comment: For instance, if `D` was a cherry-pick of `G` and OP just forgot that part, cherry-pick will fail and not understand why.  rebase looks for and skips duplicate commits. rebase skips merges, the point is rebase the linear history you're working on and it expects the merges it skipped were from the history you rebase onto. And so forth.